# PHP Date Question

Tags: php, date

I am trying to do a little bit of math using dates in PHP. I am modifying a shoutbox, and I want to implement the following functionality.

---

If post date = today, return time of post

else if date = yesterday, return "yesterday"

else date = X days ago

---

How would I use php's date functions to calculate how many days ago a timestamp is (the timestamp is formatted in UNIX time)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try this:

```
$shoutDate = date('Y-m-d', $shoutTime);
if ($shoutDate == date('Y-m-d'))
    return date('H:i', $shoutTime);

if ($shoutDate == date('Y-m-d', mktime(0, 0, 0, date('m'), date('d') - 1, date('Y'))))
    return 'yesterday';

return gregoriantojd(date('m'), date('d'), date('y')) - gregoriantojd(date('m', $shoutTime), date('d', $shoutTime), date('y', $shoutTime)) . ' days ago';
```

Answer (score 2):

In php 5.3.0 or higher, you can use [DateTime::diff](http://www.php.net/manual/en/datetime.diff.php) (aka date_diff()).

In pretty much any php, you can convert the dates to Unix timestamps and divide the difference between them by 86400 (1 day in seconds).

Comment: Don't forget that PHP 5.3 isn't out yet (as of June 2009)

Answer (score 2):

Use the fact that times are stored in seconds:

```
 $days = floor(($shoutTime - time()) / 86400) + 1; // 86400 = 24*60*60

 switch ($days) { 
   case 0:
     return date('H:i', $shoutTime);
   case -1:
     return 'yesterday';
   case 1:
     return 'tomorrow';
 }

 return "$days ago";
```

Answer (score 0):

Use DateTime class and then you have a method [diff](http://il2.php.net/manual/en/datetime.diff.php).

Answer (score 0):

Try using date_parse.
From the manual:

```
<?php
print_r(date_parse("2006-12-12 10:00:00.5"));
?>
```

Will print

```
Array
(
    [year] => 2006
    [month] => 12
    [day] => 12
    [hour] => 10
    [minute] => 0
    [second] => 0
    [fraction] => 0.5
    [warning_count] => 0
    [warnings] => Array()
    [error_count] => 0
    [errors] => Array()
    [is_localtime] => 
)
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't think it's been pointed out that you can use **[strtotime](http://php.net/strtotime)** to get "Yesterday". It makes it more *readable* (and easier to remember) than calculating dates "by hand" and is probably less error prone too.

**$int = strtotime('Yesterday');**

---

```
if(date('Y-m-d', $shoutTime) == date('Y-m-d') {
    return date('H:i:s', $shouTime);
} elseif(date('Y-m-d', $shoutTime) == date('Y-m-d', strtotime('Yesterday')) {
    return "Yesterday.";
} else {
  $days = floor($shoutTime - time() / 86400);
  return "$days ago.";
}
```